# MPAndroidChart setData Multiline

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I want to set my Bar-Data with two lines.

It's not possible to do it with **\n**.

I use MPAndroidChart Version v2.2.4.

I tried it with this code:

```
Bar1 = new BarEntry(20f,0,"20"+"\n"+"2");
Bar2 = new BarEntry(80f,1,"80"+"\n"+"8");
Bar3 = new BarEntry(60f,2,"60"+"\n"+"6");
Bar4 = new BarEntry(50f,3,"50"+"\n"+"5");
Bar5 = new BarEntry(70f,4,"70"+"\n"+"7");
Bar6 = new BarEntry(60f,5,"60"+"\n"+"6");

K1_barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

K1_barEntries.add(Bar1);
K1_barEntries.add(Bar2);
K1_barEntries.add(Bar3);
K1_barEntries.add(Bar4);
K1_barEntries.add(Bar5);
K1_barEntries.add(Bar6);

K1_barDataSet  = new BarDataSet(K1_barEntries,"");

K1_data = new BarData(labels, K1_barDataSet);
K1_barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

K1_barDataSet.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            return entry.getData().toString();
    }
});
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kWyo.png)

Comment: Show your code, your image link unreachable

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, i updated my code i hope it is helpfull and the image link is working ;)

Answer (score 1):

This lib does not support break line with "\n"

Comment: Now I try it with the Version V3.0.3 but the problem is already the same.

public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {
public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }